# Sampling with replacement from streams

Tags: algorithm, bigdata, sampling

I'm looking for efficient algorithm for sampling data with replacement from very large files (or streams). Specifically:

- There is a file large enough so that I cannot load it into memory, but can iterate through rows and write selected rows to stream;
- I need to sample *k* rows with replacement from it, total number of rows *n* is known in advance (*k* might be greater than *n*);
- Sampling has to be uniform (meaning that probability of getting any possible *k*-sized sample is same).

I know the solution for case without replacement - keep track of *k_i* and *n_i* (number of sampled and iterated rows so far up to row *i*) and take *i*-th row with probability *(k - k_i) / (n - n_i)*; but applying same logic for sampling with replacement doesn't work - I get very complicated formulas for probability to take *i*-th row (or I'm doing it wrong).

Is there an efficient way to do this?

**UPDATED**

Okay, seems that I found a semi-decent way to do this.

Let *binom(n, k)* be binomial coefficient. Number of *k*-sized samples with replacement from *n* elements is *binom(n + k - 1, n - 1)*. Hence

- Probability to select 1st element 0 times is *p0 = binom(n + k - 2, n - 2) / binom(n + k - 1, n - 1) = (n - 1) / (n + k - 1)*;
- Probability to select 1st element 1 time is *p1 = binom(n + k - 3, n - 2) / binom(n + k - 1, n - 1) = p0 * k / (n + k - 2)*;
- Probability to select 1st element 2 times is *p2 = binom(n + k - 4, n - 2) / binom(n + k - 1, n - 1) = p1 * (k - 1) / (n + k - 3)*;
- etc.

With this nice recursive formulas we can iterate through rows, roll how many times to take *i*-th row while keeping track of how many was already taken. I simulated this process with python function below:

```py
import random


def sample_wr(xs, k0):
    res = []
    n, k = len(xs), k0
    ix = 0
    
    while len(res) < k0:
        if n == 1 and k > 0:
            res.extend([xs[-1]] * k)
        else:
            m = 0
            u = random.random()
            p = (n - 1.0) / (n + k - 1.0)
            sump = p

            while sump < u:
                m += 1
                p *= (k - m + 1.0) / (n + k - m - 1.0)
                sump += p
                
            if m:
                res.extend([xs[ix]] * m)
                k -= m
            
            n -= 1
            ix += 1
        
    return tuple(res)
```

After 10M simulations on list *[1, 2, 3]* all 4-element samples seem to come out uniformly.

Thanks everyone for insights.

Comment: For sampling with replacement, you just iterate k times, each time, sampling each row with prob 1/n. Sampling probability never changes with replacement. If you dont want to loop multiple times through your file, first generate and sort the indexes you will be sampling, that way you only need to iterate at most once.

Comment: Since you seem to know *n* in advance, just choose *k* numbers from 0 to n-1, sort them, and then pick out the rows with those indexes as you iterate.

Comment: Multiple loops won't work - I'm talking of billions of rows and comparable k. Choosing indices in advance is an interesting idea, it might work; although I'd have to keep them in memory, which is challenging. Or I could also keep them in a file and read sequentially, which might be slow. I'll test it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without replacement, we check only if we select the current item with probability `1/(remaining items)`. We need only replace this with checking how many times we will select the current item, from 0 to k. This is achieved by using the binomial random variable, which models number of successes given a success probability (in our case, still `1/(remaining items)`) and a number of trials (here, k). Here is some python code to do it:

```
from numpy import random


def select_k(l, k):
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        cnt = random.binomial(k, 1. / (len(l) - i), 1)[0]
        k -= cnt
        ans += [l[i]] * cnt
    return ans + [l[-1]] * k


print(select_k([1, 2, 3], 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, it seems that it does not provide uniform sampling. I ran your function 10M times drawing samples of length 4 from (1, 2, 3) - the distribution is not uniform (script: https://pastebin.com/fvzfNghv, results: https://pastebin.com/wjasnJLU).

Comment: This is because we are sorting the lists! Note that the probability of receiving, for example, [1, 1, 1, 2], is equal to the probability of receiving [1, 1, 2, 1]. However, my code effectively sorts the output. You can simply shuffle the output, and you will find that the samples are indeed uniformly distributed.

Comment: However, if you want it to be uniformly distributed over all multisets, this would be more difficult - I'm not sure how you would approach this.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I needed uniform distributions over all multisets. It seems that here is a way to do this, I've updated my question with details. Now thinking if it can be done in parallel on Map-Reduce cluster.

Comment: @fanvacoolt If you have t threads, you could split the stream into t, and randomly select how many of the k elements will be drawn from each of the t chunks. Note that actually this is recursive! - you have the same problem, except now there are t things and you will still select k from them in total.